# authenticate with different table in django and not User

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

hello I have created a table register_Recruiter which has email and password as two of its column. Now to authenticate, from front end ( React) I am sending a post request containing email and password.But I am not able to do that.I tried looking for tutorials but no luck. Do help!!
PS: new to django -rest-framework

Comment: Please provide extra information about your problem, e.g. -  how are you receiving the request, in which function are you expecting to receive the request, how are you sending the data from the fronted, did you try to send the request directly (with a tool like `curl` or Postman), if so what error do you get, if there is no error do you have a path to check if your server is up...

Comment: it is a post request from reactjs, i have created class RecruiterRegisterList in which I have defined a post function

Answer (score 0):

This is more connected with Django itself. I guess, you need to add your new table into Django settings `AUTH_USER_MODEL=YOUR_NEW_USER_TABLE`